# Explicit call of a destructor for a c++ object

Tags: c++, destructor, object-lifetime, explicit-destructor-call

```
class box
{
public:
    double length;
    double breadth;
    double height;

~box()
{
    cout<<"destructor executed "<<"\n";
}
};

int main(){
    box mybox;
    mybox.~box();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I wrote the code in the above way. I expect the destructor ~box() will only be called once. But in actual fact, the indicator "destructor executed " was printed twice. Any hint on why?

Answer (score 4):

Because the destructor is automatically called when the local `mybox` object gets out of scope. You end up with two destructor calls for the same object, which is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by calling the [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) twice on a local object. The reference states:

> Note that calling a destructor directly for an ordinary object, such
>   as a local variable, invokes undefined behavior when the destructor is
>   called again, at the end of scope.

Leave out the `mybox.~box();` statement.

Comment: so does that mean for a local object, unless it is dynamically allocated, we should never manually call a destructor for it, since it will be called automatically at the end of a function anyway?

Comment: @Jane Placement new might be an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's printed twice, because it is called twice. First, you call it with `mybox.~box()`. Second, it will be automatically called when `mybox` goes out of scope.

If you want to manage mybox's lifetime completely manually, then use this:

```
int main() {
    alignas(box) char myboxStorage[sizeof(box)]; // allocate storage on stack for mybox
    box &mybox = *new(myboxStorage) box; // call constructor
    // use mybox here
    mybox.~box(); // call destructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called twice in your case because,

1- Destructor is called automatically just before the closing brace of main function

2- You are also calling it manually

Because of above two reasons, you have two destructor calls which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Formally, it is not called twice. It's just undefined behaviour.